# Python Top trumps

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

Any help would be appreciated
I have a dictionary containing cards names and their corresponding statistics, for example:

```
{'Bob': [1, 3, 6, 5], 'Dave': [1, 8, 5, 5], 'Steve': [1, 3, 9, 7], 'John': [6, 7, 9, 5], 'Bill': [7, 3, 9, 1], 'Rodger': [4, 5, 2, 8]}
player = dict()
computer = dict()
```

But I am unsure on how to randomly assign cards into two different variables, such that both variables contain the same number of cards, each card is used once and none of the cards are in both variables.
Anyone know how to help?

Comment: Use `random.shuffle` from the standard library on a list constructed from a `range`.  Then `pop` values from this list into your dictionary values.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `random.sample` to pick cards for `player` first, and then use set difference to obtain the remaining cards for `computer`:

```
import random
cards = {'Bob': [1, 3, 6, 5], 'Dave': [1, 8, 5, 5], 'Steve': [1, 3, 9, 7], 'John': [6, 7, 9, 5], 'Bill': [7, 3, 9, 1], 'Rodger': [4, 5, 2, 8]}
player = {name: cards[name] for name in random.sample(cards.keys(), len(cards) // 2)}
computer = {name: cards[name] for name in cards.keys() - player.keys()}
```

so that:

```
print(player)
print(computer)
```

can output:

```
{'Bob': [1, 3, 6, 5], 'John': [6, 7, 9, 5], 'Rodger': [4, 5, 2, 8]}
{'Steve': [1, 3, 9, 7], 'Dave': [1, 8, 5, 5], 'Bill': [7, 3, 9, 1]}
```